# IE7 CSS inconsistency

Tags: html, css

{link removed}

The purple links across the bottom of this gallery do not appear at all in IE7 nor is the text clickable.

I have exhausted Firebug and Google, any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: I can't see any purple links across the bottom in IE8 too. Since you apparently try to do that with JavaScript, did you try the JS debugger in the IE 8 dev tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned by Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507843/ie7-css-inconsistency/1507892#1507892), you have forgotten the closing anchor tags when generating your slider navigation in the jQuery.

You'll need to tend to your `scripts.js` file. In particular, on line 23:

```
 $('#slide-nav')
    .append('<a id="slide-link-'+i+'" href="#" 
     onclick="slider.slide('+i+'); return false;" 
     onfocus="this.blur();">'+(i+1)+'');
```

Add the closing `</a>`

```
 $('#slide-nav')
    .append('<a id="slide-link-'+i+'" href="#" 
     onclick="slider.slide('+i+'); return false;" 
     onfocus="this.blur();">'+(i+1)+'</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten the `</a>` ending tags for the links.

Comment: No I haven't. ??

<a href=""><img id="slide-img-1" src="i/cont-1.jpg" class="slide" alt="" /></a>

Comment: @Jordan: That's the images. The links are created in the jQuery code.